# How to upload CSV with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, paperclip

I have looked over the other posts about creating a CSV with Paperclip but am still a bit lost on why this isn't working. I have a method that generates a CSV string (using CSV.generate), and I try to save it to a Report in the Reports Controller with the following method:

```
  def create(type)
    case type
    when "Geo"
      csv_string = Report.generate_geo_report
    end

    @report = Report.new(type: type)
    @report.csv_file = StringIO.new(csv_string)

    if @report.save
      puts @report.csv_file_file_name
    else
      @report.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end
  end
```

However, upon execution, I get a `undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "Geo":String` error. Here is the Report model:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :csv_file, :type
  has_attached_file :csv_file, PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS.merge(
    :default_url => "//s3.amazonaws.com/production-recruittalk/media/avatar-placeholder.gif",
    :styles => {
      :"259x259" => "259x259^"
    },
    :convert_options => {
      :"259x259" => "-background transparent -auto-orient -gravity center -extent 259x259"
    }
  )

  def self.generate_geo_report
    male_count = 0
    female_count = 0
    csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Gender", "City", "State", "School", "Created At", "Updated At"]
      Athlete.all.sort_by{ |a| a.id }.each do |athlete|
        first_name = athlete.first_name || ""
        last_name = athlete.last_name || ""
        email = athlete.email || ""
        if !athlete.sports.blank?
          if athlete.sports.first.name.split(" ", 2).first.include?("Women's")
            gender = "Female"
            female_count += 1
          else
            gender = "Male"
            male_count += 1
          end
        else
          gender = ""
        end
        city = athlete.city_id? ? athlete.city.name : ""
        state = athlete.state || ""
        school = athlete.school_id? ? athlete.school.name : ""
        created_at = "#{athlete.created_at.to_date.to_s[0..10].gsub(" ", "0")} #{athlete.created_at.to_s.strip}"
        updated_at = "#{athlete.updated_at.to_date.to_s[0..10].gsub(" ", "0")} #{athlete.updated_at.to_s.strip}"
        csv << [first_name, last_name, email, gender, city, state, school, created_at, updated_at] 
      end

      csv << []
      csv << []
      csv << ["#{male_count}/#{Athlete.count} athletes are men"]
      csv << ["#{female_count}/#{Athlete.count} athletes are women"]
      csv << ["#{Athlete.count-male_count-female_count}/#{Athlete.count} athletes have not declared a gender"]
    end

    return csv_string
  end
end
```

This is being called from a cron job rake task:

```
require 'csv'

namespace :reports do
  desc "Geo-report"
  task :generate_nightly => :environment do
    Report.create("Geo")
  end
end
```

Not sure where to begin on getting this functional. Any suggestions? I've been reading Paperclip's doc but I'm a bit of a newbie to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here :)

First, it looks like you're getting your controller and model confused. In the rake task, `Report` is the model, but you're calling create as if it was the controller method. Models (aka ActiveRecord classes) take a key/value pair:

```
Report.create(type: "Geo")
```

Another issue is that you're using "type" for the name of your column, and this will tell ActiveRecord that you're using single table inheritance. That means that you have subclasses of Report. Unless you really want STI, you should rename this column.

Finally, you shouldn't have a controller method that takes an argument. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there, but controller get their arguments via the params hash.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all this! Is there a way to call the controller method create then?

Comment: Normally you don't call controller methods outside of a browser or API request. You would need to send a POST request to your application, assuming you have setup your routes using RESTful resources. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, I put all this in the model. Thank you!!